# Kruskal-Wallis test + Nemenyi post-hoc test: further multiple hypothesis correction needed?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

I have used a Kruskal-Wallis test in a one-factorial design with samples that do not meet the assumptions for one-way ANOVA. To do this I have used the function `kruskal.test` in R, as follows:

```
> kruskal.test(count ~ spray, data=InsectSprays)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  count by spray
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 54.6913, df = 5, p-value = 1.511e-10
```

I was then interested in finding out which pairwise combinations of samples were significantly different.

I understand there are various techniques to achieving this. I used the [PMCMR R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PMCMR), and specifically the `posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test` function. According to the PMCMR manual:

> Nemenyi proposed a test that originally based on rank sums and the 
>   application of the family-wise error method to control Type I error 
>   inflation, if multiple comparisons are done.

The results are as follows:

```
> posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(count ~ spray , data=InsectSprays, dist="Chisquare")

    Pairwise comparisons using Nemenyi-test with Chi-squared    
                       approximation for independent samples 

data:  count by spray 

  A      B      C       D      E     
B 0.9998 -      -       -      -     
C 0.0004 0.0001 -       -      -     
D 0.0860 0.0395 0.7427  -      -     
E 0.0117 0.0041 0.9740  0.9909 -     
F 0.9995 1.0000 6.8e-05 0.0307 0.0030

P value adjustment method: none 
Warning message:
In posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test.default(c(10, 7, 20, 14, 14, 12,  :
  Ties are present. Chi-sq was corrected for ties.
```

Now to my question. Do I have to *further* adjust the p-values returned by the `posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test()` above (for example, by passing them to `p.adjust()` with a `"BH"` option?).

I was under the impression I should not, because a posthoc Nemenyi test, as quoted above, seems to already control for multiple comparisons. However, I am a bit confused by the output line from `posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test()`:

```
P value adjustment method: none
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm wondering the same thing. Table 5 in http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/demsar06a/demsar06a.pdf seems to suggest that the critical values changes per number of comparisons with Nemenyi's test, suggesting that further correction is not necessary

Comment: @StuartLacy Yes I did find an answer. I contacted the author of the PMCMR package directly. He confirmed that no further correction is necessary. He directed me towards inequalities n.5 and n.6 from the PMCMR vignette (taken from [Sachs, 1997]) which show that the family wise error is already accounted for the Nemenyi test.